# What is the antiderivative of $\csc^2 \sqrt{x}$?

Tags: calculus

Please how can I solve the antiderivative of $\csc^2 \sqrt{x}$ ?

Comment: Let $x=u^2$, then perform an integration by parts.

Comment: @Ron Thank you so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\int dx \, \csc^2{\sqrt{x}} &= 2 \int du \, u \, \csc^2{u} \\ &= -2u \, \cot{u} + 2\int du \, \cot{u} \\ &= -2u \, \cot{u} + 2\log{|\sin{u}|} + C \\ &= -2\sqrt{x} \, \cot{\sqrt{x}} + \log{\sin^2{\sqrt{x}}} + C \end{align} $$

Comment: but if you chose u^2 = x, and du=1/2 (x)^1/2 dx, so what is dv?

Comment: @user2849967: what is this $dv$?  You want $dx$ in terms of $du$, which I have supplied.  Why would you want $du$ in terms of $x$?

Comment: I think if we use integration by parts we should have u and dv

Comment: @user2849967: Oh, I see - you are married to $u dv$, etc. notation of integration by parts as taught in Calc II.  Right, so $dv = \csc^2{u} du$.

Comment: ok thank you, but I have question pleas you chose u=x^(1/2), so du= 1/2[x^(-1/2)]dx right ?

Comment: @user2849967: Well, the way to look at it is as I put it, because you want the integral over $u$, not $x$.  So it's $x=u^2$, $dx=2 u du$.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11218/discussion-between-user2849967-and-ron-gordon)